# openpyxl: apply style to selected group of cells

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to apply a cell style using openpyxl.

If you take a look at this image:

[image]

I would like to appply the **green scale** from 0% to 100% but only to the **section of interest** into the table. As you can see, this section of interest is from B2 to D21, without the headers...

For this pourpose I have tried the following...but the result is not as good as desired

```
ws.conditional_formatting.add('B2:B21',
                openpyxl.formatting.ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=0, start_color=openpyxl.styles.Color('E3F6CE'),
                end_type='percentile', end_value=100, end_color=openpyxl.styles.Color('3ADF00'))
                )
ws.conditional_formatting.add('C2:C21',
                openpyxl.formatting.ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=0, start_color=openpyxl.styles.Color('E3F6CE'),
                end_type='percentile', end_value=100, end_color=openpyxl.styles.Color('3ADF00'))
                )
ws.conditional_formatting.add('D2:D21',
                openpyxl.formatting.ColorScaleRule(start_type='percentile', start_value=0, start_color=openpyxl.styles.Color('E3F6CE'),
                end_type='percentile', end_value=100, end_color=openpyxl.styles.Color('3ADF00'))
            )
```

So the basic question would be how to apply the style to B2:D21, skipping the cells B1, C1 and D1 and setting the green scale from 0% to 100% for all the cells included.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do this in Excel and inspect the file in openpyxl. A lot of the conditional formatting rules are somewhat counterintuitive but basically a rule for `B2:D21` should be possible.

Comment: thanks Charlie, just one observation....I have not tested this but, if I write B2:D21, it will take C1 and D1....or not??

Comment: Why don't you try it? To Excel there is no difference whether a range covers a single column or row or multiple ones.